# C# or JAVA library for gesture recognition from webcam?

Tags: c#, java, gesture-recognition, gesture

I have a project for gesture recognition. I was wondering how can use C# or Java to program it? Is there any special library? Do I need programming or do I need a special device rather than a webcam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)?

> OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision)
>   is a library of programming functions
>   for real time computer vision.
>
> Example applications of the OpenCV
>   library are Human-Computer Interaction
>   (HCI); Object Identification,
>   Segmentation and Recognition; Face
>   Recognition; Gesture Recognition;
>   Camera and Motion Tracking, Ego
>   Motion, Motion Understanding;
>   Structure From Motion (SFM); Stereo
>   and Multi-Camera Calibration and Depth
>   Computation; Mobile Robotics.

Comment: hi Smith, tanx for your reply. I found iGesture framework, for java, nut unfortunately it has not been update since 2007, and its not a complete framwork. 
OpenCV is for c/c++ programmers, but I need something to be able to program in Java or C#. do you have any idea?

Comment: You could use [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/), which is an interface to OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

There are [C# bindings](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/) for [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) with a few gesture projects listen in this [very similar StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083318/open-source-video-gesture-recognition-library-in-c), from which I quote:

> I've heard that [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/opencvdotnet/) is pretty awesome (check out the [AForge.Vision.Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) namespace).
>
> A quick Google query gave me this: [Video Hands Gesture Recognition in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083318/open-source-video-gesture-recognition-library-in-c)
>
> This is also interesting: [Video Motion Detection Algorithms in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx)

Comment: many thanks, I'm going to check them right now to find out how I can run my project

Comment: after trying OpenCV to work with Java or C# for couple of days, and achieving no result. I have decided to use AForge with C#. but couldnt find any tutorial to help me for developing. do you have any Idea how I can use it for gesture recognition to be able to specified some gestures and base on them computer run some commands???

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [AForge.Net](http://aforge.net)

It rocks alot .. and is very easy to implement. There is a Code Project Article as well [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/aforge.aspx)

Comment: @niq, please post clean/not blind links.

Comment: after trying OpenCV to work with Java or C# for couple of days, and achieving no result. I have decided to use AForge with C#. but couldnt find any tutorial to help me for developing. do you have any Idea how I can use it for gesture recognition to be able to specified some gestures and base on them computer run some commands???

Answer (score 0):

You can use emguCV.net. it is a wrapper for OpenCV which can be used in C#. Also they have covered almost all the functionalities of OpenCV and they provide sufficient documentations to make development easy.