# is it possible in java to detect lip movement

Tags: image, face-detection

i just want to know that is it possible that can we detect lip movement in a video using java....the exact thing is that i m looking to do a project in which we can zoom in at a position using a camera  where there is some lip movement (or voice) in a frame of video...pleae tell me is it possible.....advice expected please reply asap

Comment: If any sort of data analysis can be done by a program, it can be done in Java.  There is nothing especially in Java to address this issue, so you'd have to design and program it yourself or use outside libraries.

Answer (score 1):

No mainstream programming language has built-in support for detecting lip movement; you'd need an external library to do that with Java. A good place to start would be [the Stack Overflow question on facial recognition libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953714/face-recognition-library).

Answer (score 0):

There are answers for this at [C# or JAVA library for gesture recognition from webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154861/c-or-java-library-for-gesture-recognition-from-webcam), but yes, it surely is possible.